# Adding nested dict key to plist

Tags: macos, bash, shell, terminal, plist

I am trying to add these keys to the root of a plist:

```
<dict>
  <key>11</key>
    <dict>
      <key>FeatureLockdown</key>
        <dict>
          <key>bUpdater</key>
          <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I have tried using PlistBuddy and defaults. I can't seem to get it to work.

Does anyone know a way to properly format this via terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do this by looking at the [man page for `PlistBuddy`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/PlistBuddy.8.html) and playing around in the Terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :11 dict" Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :11:FeatureLockdown dict" Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :11:FeatureLockdown:bUpdater bool false" Info.plist
```

which gives a result of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>11</key>
    <dict>
        <key>FeatureLockdown</key>
        <dict>
           <key>bUpdater</key>
           <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
...
...
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I realized my mistake was trying to do it all in one batch. Thank you for the help!